# Prototype equivalent of jQuery eq method

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Given the following html code:

```
<ul id="fun">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

I can select the third li in jquery like so:

```
$('#fun li').eq(2);
```

In prototype I know I can do something like :

```
$("fun").select('li').each(function(i,v){
    if(v == 2){/*do whatever*/}
});
```

So what I'm asking is does prototype have a method like jquerys eq that allows you to select a particularly indexed element in an array of elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some other ways

```
$('fun').down(2);
//for the 2nd child of #fun no matter what element
```

or

```
$('fun').down('li',2)
//for the 2nd child <li> element
```

And you don't need to wrap the result in another `$()` because the element result is already extended, and the `down()` method returns just one element so you do not need to add the array index `[2]`

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/down/

Comment: ah.  While, the other answers are very useful, this is a better overall answer as it more specifically answer the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you guys forgot about `$$`:

```
$$('#fun li')[2]
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DpYd/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fun li').eq(2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
$($('#fun li')[2]);
```

So you can use native javascript to accomplish this.

```
$($("fun").select('li')[2]).whatever
```

Comment: hmmmm.  Well thats mighty handy.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `$$` for complex selectors?